# merge sort stack overflow error

Tags: java, mergesort

I'm writing a merge sort function, but can't get past this stack overflow error at line 15, line 16 of my code which is where the recursive call happens.

```
public class MergeSort {

     private int [] tempArray;



    public void mSort(int [] A, int low, int high)
    {
        if(high-low >1)
        {
            mSort(A, low, (high/2));  **Line 15 ERROR**
            mSort(A, ((high / 2) + 1), high);**Line 16 ERROR**
            Merge(A, low, (high / 2 + 1), high);
        }

    }


    public void Merge(int [] A, int low, int mid, int high)
    {
        int length = high - low +1;
        int indexlow = low;
        int indexhigh = mid;
        int index = low;
        tempArray = new int[length];
        while(indexlow < mid || indexhigh < high)
        {
            if(indexlow >= mid)
            {

                tempArray[index] = A[indexhigh];
                index = index + 1;
                indexhigh = indexhigh + 1;
            }
            else if(indexhigh > high)
            {

                tempArray[index] = A[indexlow];
                index = index + 1;
                indexlow = indexlow +1;
            }
            else if(A[indexlow] <= A[indexhigh])
            {

                tempArray[index] = A[indexlow];
                index = index + 1;
                indexlow = indexlow + 1;
            }
            else
            {

                tempArray[index] = A[indexhigh];
                index = index + 1;
                indexhigh = indexhigh +1;
            }
        }
        for(int i = low; i <= high; i++)
        {
            A[i] = tempArray[i];
        }
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
        int A = 7/2;
        int [] inputArray = {4, 10, 1, 5, 3, 8, 7, 6};
        MergeSort myMergeSort = new MergeSort();

        myMergeSort.mSort(inputArray, 0, inputArray.length-1);

        for(int i:inputArray)
        {
            System.out.print(i);
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println(A);
    }
}
```

can someone please help me understand what is wrong with my code? I am lost and can't comprehend. I've tried reading all over the website but still can't understand it.

Comment: Which type of Error show @MitterHai

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at com.Hai.company.MergeSort.mSort(MergeSort.java:15)
 at com.Hai.company.MergeSort.mSort(MergeSort.java:16)
 ...

Comment: Your boundaries in the recursive calls do not look right to me.

Comment: First try with simple input, {0,1,2}. I see that sorting not happening.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I'm trying to sort an array of size 8, can you explain to me why my boundaries in the recursive call doesn't look right to you?

Comment: @Adi, so with A = {0,1,2}, we get the initial function call as, MergeSort(A, 0, A.length-1). The two recursive calls, MergeSort(A, 0, 1) and MergeSort(A, 2, 2). Why wouldn't this sort, Adi?

Comment: The sorting works for the first half of the array. For the second half, there comes a point where the `high` value is lower than the `low` value.

Comment: @Flaom, I just wrote the second half recursive call by hand, I can't see how there would be a point where high can ever be less than the low value which is (high/2 +1) for the second half. Can you explain a little more of how you see it becoming as you would say? Thanks, Flaom.

Comment: Your code [is full of problems](http://rextester.com/NANIA88542), and when I input an array `{4, 10, 1}` I got an extra fourth number in the output.  I would recommend starting with a textbook implementation of merge sort (e.g. Cormen) and going from there.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, thanks for the feedback, and your recommendation, Tim. I'll look into that. I implemented this code based on a pseudo code that was provided to us from the class book. I have had problems understanding this author since I've begun this class.

Comment: At the point where `low=4` and `high=7`, `high/2=3`, so the method call `msort(A, low, (high / 2))` is passing the incorrect values. `high/2` is not a good way of getting the mid point. The midpoint is better calculated using `(high+low)/2`

Comment: Unfortunately, this fix reveals issues with your `Merge` function, so you should make sure that you properly implemented that from your pseudocode

Comment: @Flaom, thank you. I see what you mean now. I wish that I can show you a picture of this textbook's pseudo code, because I tried to follow it, and this is the logic that it uses.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I got the book that you recommended. So far its been an amazing resource.  Thank you very much for sharing the book's existence, Tim.

Comment: @MitterHai Yeah CLR is pretty much the standard used by universities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in

```
if (high-low > 1) {
    mSort(A, low, (high/2));  **Line 15 ERROR**
    mSort(A, ((high / 2) + 1), high);**Line 16 ERROR**
    Merge(A, low, (high / 2 + 1), high);
}
```

If `high = 3` and `low = 2`, it will cause infinite loop, so `stackoverflow` error will be thrown.

And please notice, when `high - low == 1`, you should also merge them.

Here is a working version:

```
public class MergeSort {

    private static int [] tempArray;

    public void mSort(int [] A, int low, int high) {
        if (high > low) {
            int mid = low + (high - low) / 2;
            mSort(A, low, mid);
            mSort(A, mid + 1, high);
            Merge(A, low, mid + 1, high);
        }
    }

    public void Merge(int [] A, int low, int mid, int high) {
        int indexlow = low;
        int indexhigh = mid;
        int index = low;
        while(indexlow < mid || indexhigh <= high) {
            if(indexlow >= mid) {
                tempArray[index] = A[indexhigh];
                indexhigh++;
            } else if(indexhigh > high) {
                tempArray[index] = A[indexlow];
                indexlow++;
            } else if(A[indexlow] <= A[indexhigh]) {
                tempArray[index] = A[indexlow];
                indexlow++;
            } else {
                tempArray[index] = A[indexhigh];
                indexhigh++;
            }
            index++;
        }
        for(int i = low; i <= high; i++) {
            A[i] = tempArray[i];
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] inputArray = {4, 10, 1, 5, 3, 8, 7, 6};
        tempArray = new int[inputArray.length];
        MergeSort myMergeSort = new MergeSort();
        myMergeSort.mSort(inputArray, 0, inputArray.length-1);
        for(int i : inputArray) {
            System.out.print(i);
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to thank you for taking the time out to correctly solve my issue. I was able to study your code and understood what went wrong. Thank you.

Comment: @MitterHai no problem :)